# Merge multiple small PDFs on A4 size format

Tags: 12.04, pdf

I have a PDF file with approximatly 300 pages (A4). On each page some text with lines are plotted, which take up only a third of the page size. So I want to get rid of the white space everywhere.
I used the burst command to create for every page a single PDF-file which have no white space on it. Now I need to join these PDFs on A4 papersize. When I use PDFTK I get several pages, which have no whitespace, but when I want to print them, they will be printed out on separate pages.
Has someone an idea how to handle this problem??

Comment: What commands did you use exactly? Please copy-paste. If possible, upload a sample document that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yqou could also try the script "pdfjoin" and "pdfnup" command line programs from the pdfjam packages.

However, I would include the PDFs in a LaTeX document, and let LaTeX worry about how to fit them best on a page.

First, you need to install LaTeX:

```
sudo apt-get install pdflatex
```

Next, create a file "joined.tex" like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=15cm]{file1.pdf}
\includegraphics[width=15cm]{file2.pdf}
\includegraphics[width=15cm]{file3.pdf}
% ...etc, for each of your pdf files
\end{document}
```

Finally, run (in a terminal)

```
pdflatex joined.tex
```

Hopefully, you will get your file in joined.pdf